# how to get value after the record has been save?

Tags: acumatica

I have an issue after saving the record in Stock Items screen, it doesn't work the way I want it to work.

I want to get the concatenated values after saving the record.

I customized the description field to concatenate the values ​​of some attributes.

[image]

I have all the following code inside RowPersisted event, the way I get that data is by using BQL query:

```
protected void InventoryItem_RowPersisted(PXCache cache, PXRowPersistedEventArgs e, PXRowPersisted InvokeBaseHandler)
{
        string attr = "";
        string itemClassDesc = "";
        string itemClassCD = "";

        if (InvokeBaseHandler != null)
            InvokeBaseHandler(cache, e);
        var row = (InventoryItem)e.Row;

        PXResultset<InventoryItem> result =
        PXSelectJoin<InventoryItem,
            InnerJoin<CSAnswers,
                On<CSAnswers.refNoteID, Equal<InventoryItem.noteID>>,
            LeftJoin<CSAttributeDetail,
                On<CSAttributeDetail.attributeID, Equal<CSAnswers.attributeID>,
                And<CSAttributeDetail.valueID, Equal<CSAnswers.value>>>,
            InnerJoin<CSAttribute,
                On<CSAttribute.attributeID, Equal<CSAnswers.attributeID>>>>>,
        Where<InventoryItem.inventoryID, Equal<Current<InventoryItem.inventoryID>>>,
        OrderBy<Asc<CSAnswers.attributeID>>>.Select(this.Base);

        foreach (PXResult<InventoryItem, CSAnswers, CSAttributeDetail, CSAttribute> record in result)
        {
            InventoryItem inventory = (InventoryItem)record;
            CSAnswers answers = (CSAnswers)record;
            CSAttributeDetail detail = (CSAttributeDetail)record;
            CSAttribute attribute = (CSAttribute)record;

            switch (itemClassCD)
            {
                case "0531":
                if (attribute.AttributeID == "A1" || attribute.AttributeID == "A2" || attribute.AttributeID == "A3")
                    {
                        if (attribute.AttributeID == "A2")
                            attr += answers.Value + " ";
                        else
                        if (attribute.ControlType == 1)
                            attr += attribute.Description + " " + answers.Value + " ";
                        else
                            attr += attribute.Description + " " + detail.Description + " ";
                    }
                    break;

                default:

                    break;
            }
        }
        cache.SetValue<InventoryItem.descr>(row, itemClassDesc + " " + attr);
}
```

It works well because the description field concatenates the values when I press the save button but it always get a previous record.

Can you help me with this?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `RowPersisted` event is fired after the item has been saved. You need to use the `RowPersisting` event or override the `Persist` function of the graph and run your code before invoking the base function.

Comment: I would strongly suggest using the RowPersisting event as suggested. Many issues are related to attempting to persist after persist as occurred which causes logical issues. By using RowPersisting and avoiding RowPersisted/misusing Persist override you can avoid this class of errors.

Comment: @HuguesBeauséjour I thought that overriding RowPersisting was discouraged and that the best practice was to override Persist. I also think it's cleaner/simpler to listed to RowPersisted for this particular use case...

Comment: In practice documentation is lacking for Persist override so a lot of issues are related to misuse of advanced features in that event which were randomly copy pasted from unofficial sources. Typically misuse of unnecessary Transaction Scope, obscure cache manipulation methods, misuse of PXDatabase class and a lot more. Very common, when using RowPersisting none of these patterns are encountered and since most of the case concern simple assignation a one liner in RowPersisting is sufficient.

Comment: That said both solution provided works just fine when properly implemented so I upvoted answer.

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay, I tried to use RowPersisting but I got the same previous record. I'm not sure if there is an issue using BQL statements in RowPersisting event, but I need all this to happen after saving